# Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-amplify/core'

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Trying to create a React App using amplify authentication, stuck with this error

Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-amplify/core' in '..\node_modules@aws-amplify\api\lib-esm'

I have been referring to these two links:

- https://dev.to/dabit3/the-complete-guide-to-user-authentication-with-the-amplify-framework-2inh
- https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js

What have I already tried:

- deleting node_modules and reinstalling the project
- trying to explicitly install @aws-amplify/core using npm (This throws a separate error)

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue working with AWS Datastore which also depends on @amplify/core. Here's how I resolved it:

```
npm i @aws-amplify/core --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

React component:

```
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core
```

The legacy peer deps flag was required in my case as the install React version was greater than the version required for amplify/core. You may also need to `amplify init` or `amplify pull` first if you've not already done so.

Answer (score 2):

The perfect solution is as mentioned above. I found this after a lot of research. Need to install @aws-amplify/core. But along with that in my react app, I have to install some more packages for cognito to work properly.

```
npm i @aws-amplify/core --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/storage --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/interactions --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/auth --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/api --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/analytics --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/xr --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same errors after upgrading `@aws-amplify/ui-react` from 1.x to 4.x

I have tried the below steps and errors got resolved after that.

1. Removed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` files.
2. `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Do `npm install aws-amplify@latest` sometimes this problem happens cuz the version i think.

After stop the project and run it again.